# React: Search box and filter map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Expected results:
Type keywords in the `input` to search, and filter the list of posts.

Below is my code in React, when I type in the search box, `searchSpace` did get called, `console.log(search_keywords)` and  `console.log('filter', data)` show up in Console. But the `filteredData` did not update and my list of posts are still the same. What am I missing here?

```
const Blog = () => {
  const [posts] = useState([]);

  let filteredData = posts;

  let search_keywords = "";
  const searchSpace = (event) => {
    search_keywords = event.target.value;
    console.log(search_keywords)

    filteredData = posts.filter((data)=>{
      if(data.title.toLowerCase().includes(search_keywords)){
        console.log('filter', data)
        return data
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input placeholder="search..." id="search" type="text" onChange={(e)=>searchSpace(e)} />
      {
        filteredData.map((v, i) => {
           return <Card post={v} key={i} />;
        })
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

*omitted some codes that are not relevant*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain a `filteredData` state as well. Setting it will trigger a re-render. Think of `posts` as read-only data.

```
const Blog = () => {
      const [posts,setPosts] = useState([]);
      let [filteredData,setFilteredData] = useState([]);

      let search_keywords = "";
      const searchSpace = (event) => {
        search_keywords = event.target.value;
        console.log(search_keywords)

        filteredData = posts.filter((data)=>{
          if(data.title.toLowerCase().includes(search_keywords)){
            console.log('filter', data)
            return data
          }
        });
        setFilteredData(filteredData);
      }

      return (
        <>
          <input placeholder="search..." id="search" type="text" onChange={(e)=>searchSpace(e)} />
          {
            filteredData.map((v, i) => {
               return <Card post={v} key={i} />;
            })
          }
        </>
      );
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I changed the `const` to `let [filteredData,setFilteredData] = useState([]);`

Comment: Actually const will work as well. When you will assign filteredData to result of posts.filter, that filteredData will be a separate local variable in the searchSpace function.